# Chosen jquery. how can I change from multiselect to single

Tags: jquery-chosen

I have chosen multiselectable.I want to change chosen from multiselect to single select on javascript code. I will send some ajax post and according to response value, I must change property of chosen. From multiselect to singleselect or oppsitely.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to manually destroy the Chosen instance, change the `multiple` attribute of the raw select element, and initialize the plugin again.

```
var $select = $('.my-select');
$select.chosen('destroy');
$select.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
$select.chosen();
```

or the inverse

```
$select.chosen('destroy'); 
$select.removeAttr('multiple');
$select.chosen();
```

Not super clean but Chosen doesn't appear to have a "rerender from source element" method, other than changes to the options.

Answer (score 0):

Add or remove the attribute  `multiple` on your select element.   Chosen watches that to determine it.

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html